# Detect connection loss when working with Raspberry Pi's Remote GPIO feature (in Python)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am controlling the GPIO pins of a Raspberry Pi over a WiFi network from a control device (in this case a Linux laptop), which is running a Python programme that uses the gpiozero library's Remote GPIO feature to control the pins.

In the event that the WiFi connection between the control device and the Raspberry Pi is severed, I want to be able to detect that this has happened so that I can take measures to ensure that the programme on the control device does not lock up.

To give an example of the most likely scenario, let's say that the robot the Raspberry Pi is installed in drives out of WiFi range.

The function that I am using to quit the control device programme is set up to automatically tell tell the robot to stop moving before quitting the programme. This is done by setting the values on the GPIO pins that connect to the motor driver.

Problem is, when I simulate a connection break by turning off the WiFi on the Raspberry Pi, if I then click on the quit button on the control device programme, the code execution just seems to stop at the point where it is trying to set the relevant GPIO pins to stop the robot's motors.

My suspicion is that the control device programme is just waiting forever for a socket response that will never come.

In order to address this problem, can anyone give me advice on doing any of the following:

- Detecting when the connection between the control device is cut, and running a function in response.
- Setting a timeout on the Remote GPIO connection, which I can then catch with a try statement.
- Any other fix you think might work (please give details).

Thanks.

Comment: why don't you just ping your raspberry?

Comment: @Sadap (Blank Facial Expression) Because I don't know how to do that. Can it be done from within the Python programme?

Comment: google "python ping". I'm sure that you will find something

Comment: By using selectors you can easily detect when a socket connection is done. Maybe this [link](https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/) could help you.